# Wierd terminal display glitch in c, Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, virtual-machine

When I run the first code it with "\n" at the end of every print statement it gives me the expected output which is in case of `num` == `35`

```
The generated sequence:
35
106
53
160...
```

code to generate collatz sequence:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fd[2], fd1[2], num = atoi(argv[1]), id = getpid();
    
    printf("\nRecieved number: %d\n", num);

    if(num > 0)
    {
        printf("The generated sequence: \n");
        
        while(num > 1)
        {   
            pipe(fd);
            pipe(fd1);

            if(fork()) //parent process
            {
                printf("%d \n", num);
                int n;
                close(fd[0]); //closing read end..
                close(fd1[1]); //closing write end..

                write(fd[1], &num, sizeof(num));
                wait(NULL);
                read(fd1[0], &n, sizeof(n));

                num = n;

                close(fd[1]);
                close(fd1[0]);

                if(num == 1) {
                    printf("1\n");
                    exit(0);
                }
            }

            else    //child process
            {
                int n;
                close(fd[1]); //closing write end..
                close(fd1[0]); //closing read end..

                read(fd[0], &n, sizeof(n));

                if(n%2 == 0)
                    n /= 2;
                
                else   
                    n = 3*n+1;

                write(fd1[1], &n, sizeof(n));

                close(fd1[1]);
                close(fd[0]);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        printf("\nERROR: number should be positive!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

...But the problem is if I change the printing line

```
printf("%d \n", num);
```

to

```
printf("%d, ", num);
```

my output will have repetitions i.e.

it will print:
with `n=35`

```
sequence: 35 sequence: 35, 106 sequence: 35, 106, 53 sequence: 35, 106, 53, 160...
```

Although printing on new line fixes the repetition problem, I don't want to print every number of sequence on new line.

Comment: What compels you to use forks and pipes to implement this series?  Can you not just loop on the new value of `n`, and perform that same two tests for even or odd until `n` equals `1`?

Comment: @ryyker: The teacher. It is an exercise in using forks and pipes, not an exercise in examining the Collatz problem.

Comment: When you remove `\n` from printf, your also removed the `stdout` flush, your problem could come from here. Try to add `fflush(stdout);` after your `printf` call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a newline character, the output remains in the program‘s buffer. When the program forks, the buffer is duplicated along with the rest of the program. Eventually, both the parent and the child write more output, including what was in the buffer. So the output appears multiple times.

You can eliminate this duplication of the buffer contents by flushing the buffer forking. Put `fflush(stdout);` immediately before `if (fork())`. Flushing the buffer (which is inside the executing process) writes its contents to the stream (which is outside the executing process) and empties it.